# Coordinator layout, activity below toolbar

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout

I have an app with a coordinator layout that uses sliding tabs and a view pager in a coordinator layout.  I am trying to place an activity (list) below the toolbar.  I have tried a number of different things but always the list overlaps the toolbar.

Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:padding="2dp"
            app:titleMarginStart="20dp"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"/>

        <com.passwordstore.utility.SlidingTabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="4dp"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:foreground="@drawable/shadow"/>

       <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">
        </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

    </LinearLayout>

    <FrameLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" android:id="@+id/frameLayout">

        <include layout="@layout/activity_password_list" />

    </FrameLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton android:id="@+id/fabNew"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin" android:src="@drawable/ic_add_white_24dp"
        app:layout_anchor="@+id/pager"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 26):

Just add `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` to the layout that needs to be under the toolbar

Answer (score 3):

please try this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

     <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:padding="2dp"
            app:titleMarginStart="20dp"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"/>

        <com.passwordstore.utility.SlidingTabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="4dp"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:foreground="@drawable/shadow"/>

       <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">
        </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below= "@id/appbar"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" android:id="@+id/frameLayout">

        <include layout="@layout/activity_password_list" />

    </FrameLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton android:id="@+id/fabNew"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin" android:src="@drawable/ic_add_white_24dp"
        app:layout_anchor="@+id/pager"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I removed **linearLayout** and replace it with **appBarLayout** also , added **android:layout_below** in your **Framelayout**

good luck

Comment: I can't use appbarlayout because my list doesn't scroll with the viewpager so had to change it.

Comment: ok, keep your Linearlayout but just add android:layout_below= "@id/yourLinearLayoutID" in your FrameLayout and see if it solved it

Comment: You can't use layout_below in a CoordinatorLayout

Comment: Its not working. Bottom view not showing. Please suggest for same

Answer (score 0):

You could replace the CoordinatorLayout with a LinearLayout (with android:orientation="vertical").

```
<RelativeLayout>
    <LinearLayout> (replaces the coordinator layout>
        <AppBarLayout/>
        <FrameLayout/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <FloatingActionButton/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Then I have trouble with the floating action button

Comment: Place this new LinearLayout in a RelativeLayout. And the FAB at the same level as the LinearLayout (direct child of the RelativeLayout)